# Struggling to Align Bootstrap Containers with Flexbox

Tags: html, css, containers, bootstrap-5

I'm facing difficulty in aligning Bootstrap containers using Flexbox. I have two containers, one at the bottom and the other at the top, and I want to position the top container immediately above the bottom one, aligning it with the top border of the bottom container.

I tried various combinations of Bootstrap classes and custom CSS, including position: absolute and flexbox, but none of them achieved the desired result. I was expecting the top container to be correctly positioned just above the bottom container, with their top borders aligned, while still adhering to Bootstrap's layout system.

Comment: You've not provided any code examples

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.